# why cant i "update" data to the database from netbeans interface.

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans

```html
<html>
<body>
<pre>





geting a error when click on the update button as : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_customer'. Cannot insert duplication key in object 'dbo.Customer'. The duplication key value is ()."   



private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        
       try{
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=77OOP062;user=sa;password=hnd";
        Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection(url);


String value1=jTextFieldCustomerName.getText();
String value2=jTextFieldHomeAddress.getText();
String value3=jTextFieldNIC.getText();
String value4=jTextFieldEmailAddress.getText();
String value5=jTextFieldContactNo.getText();
String value6=jLabel7.getText();


pst=conn.prepareStatement("update Customer set CustomerName=?,HomeAddress=?,NIC=?,EmailAddress=?,ContactNo=?,InvoiceNo=?"); 
pst.setString(1,value1);
pst.setString(2,value2);
pst.setString(3,value3);
pst.setString(4,value4);
pst.setString(5,value5);
pst.setString(6,value6);
pst.executeUpdate();
              
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Güncellendi");



}catch(Exception e){;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);


}
  distable();
       
    }   






</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

geting a error when click on the update button as : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_customer'. Cannot insert duplication key in object 'dbo.Customer'. The duplication key value is ()."

Comment: what column is the primary key in customer table

Comment: Where is the `WHERE` clause from your `UPDATE` statement? This way tries to set all rows ...

Comment: 3rd column is the primary and it is the NIC..

Comment: should need to change set to WHERE from the statment

Comment: why are u updating the primary key??

Comment: its says incorrect keyword where" pst=conn.prepareStatement("update Customer where CustomerName=?,HomeAddress=?,NIC=?,EmailAddress=?,ContactNo=?,InvoiceNo=?");

Comment: @Anver `where` in `update` comes after the `set` column list

Comment: if the primary key missed typed by the user it should able to change right. so thats why i thought it would be. but i am not specifically focusing into primary. any key field should be able to change the data when necessary ....

Comment: You need to look at the basic syntax of an update statement. You need BOTH SET and WHERE in an update statement.

Comment: ok i got it. but can you let me know what should WHERE be equal to because i have already assigned the field names into the statement

Answer (score 1):

since your `update` statement doesn't include a `where` clause, your statement tries  to update all rows in the table and since you've put primary key column `NIC` in the update statement, it also get's overwritten but after the first write rdbms realizes your putting the same value in `NIC` column(which isn't allowed as pk must be unique)  and thus gives you the error.

use a `where` clause to filter rows u want to update and don't update the pk.

Comment: actually he data is not even overwriting its doing nothing. when i select the displayed day from the interface. its not showing in the interface "input fields". when i click update it shows :::geting a error when click on the update button as : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_customer'. Cannot insert duplication key in object 'dbo.Customer'. The duplication key value is ()."

Comment: ok i got it. but can you let me know what should WHERE be equal to because i have already assigned the field names into the statement